# Search and replace all special characters in vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new in vba, my aim is replace special characters eg: , into COMMA e.t.c. how I write the code, If i followed the below code my code become very length. Is it any alternative method ?

```
Dim comma As Range
For Each comma In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With comma.Find
      .Text = ","
      .Replacement.Text = "#@KE_COMMA@#"
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  Next comma
```

Comment: What do you mean by `special characters`, do you have a collection in mind, specific punctuation etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
Sub shalu()
s = sss(",", "Repace_Comma")
s = sss(".", "Replace_dot")
s = sss("-", "replace_hyphen")
End Sub

Public Function sss(A As String, B As String) As String

Dim myword As Range

 For Each myword In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With myword.Find
      .Text = A
      .Replacement.Text = B
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  Next myword
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I use, when I want to replace something in Excel. You may change it a bit, so it works in Word as well.

```
Public Sub remove_space_in_string()

Dim r_range As Range

For Each r_range In Selection
    r_range = Trim(r_range)
    r_range = Replace(r_range, vbTab, "")
    r_range = Replace(r_range, " ", "")
    r_range = Replace(r_range, Chr(160), "")
Next r_range

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please tell about this code r_range = Replace(r_range, Chr(160), "") and r_range = Replace(r_range, vbTab, "")

Comment: It is just a code that I use, to remove any kind of blanks in the selected range. Thus, it catches " ", tab and Chr(160).

Answer (score 0):

What i suggest is store all the special characters and replacemnt values in array and iterate throgh all the ranges like how you do.

```
Dim comma As Range
For i=0 to Ubound(arraySpCahr)-1
For Each comma In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
With comma.Find
  .Text = arraySpCahr(i) ' arraySpCahr(0)="," (1)="-"...etc
  .Replacement.Text = "#@KE_COMMA@#"
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Next comma
Next i
```

Comment: if I replace "," or "-" the replacement string is always same, my required output is If I replace comma it should be #@KE_COMMA@# ,If I replace hyphen it should be #@KE_HYPYEN@# , Is it possible ?

Comment: Then Have 2 dimensional arry such that Array coloum1 have your characters and coloumn2 have your replacment text. If you feel it a bit complicated Use another arry2 which stores the replacemnet arry.

Comment: you mean dim comma()
comma = range(",:#@KE_COMMA@#")  is it correct